# Facebook not returning e-mail for user

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-oauth

I am trying to implement Facebook authentication into an existing ASP.NET MVC 5 application using the Microsoft OWIN OAuth libraries and cannot find a way how to get user's email address. The registration looks like this:

```
var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "YYY",
    AppSecret = "ZZZ"
};

options.Scope.Add("public_profile");
options.Scope.Add("email");
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

The scope `email` is added into the options.

On authentication, in `ExternalLoginCallback` method in the controller, the `email` is null with this code:

```
AuthenticateResult authResult = await authenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

ClaimsIdentity externalIdentity = authResult.Identity;
string email = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
```

Also tried this to no avail:

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var email = loginInfo.Email;
```

The Json data returned from Facebook does not seem to contain the e-mail address:

```
{"id":"989197284440871","first_name":"Martin","gender":"male","last_name":"Stauf\u010d\u00edk","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/989197284440871\/","locale":"cs_CZ","name":"Martin Stauf\u010d\u00edk","timezone":2,"updated_time":"2014-10-18T16:14:08+0000","verified":true}
```

Is it a problem with Facebook not returning the address or is something missing in the code? Any help offered would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming "email" is the correct name for the scope, I'd say you asked for the email scope, but did the user also grant it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I have just upgraded the application to use the latest components MVC 5.2.3 and OWIN 3.0.1, and now the authentication is working. The code to get the e-mail address is:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    var email = loginInfo.Email;

    ...
}
```

This is the default code that comes with a new ASP.NET MVC web project created in Visual Studio. Whatever the problem was it is fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the below code and it works

```
var loginInformation = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
if (loginInformation != null && loginInformation.Identity != null &&
        loginInformation.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var claimsIdentity = loginInformation.Identity;
    var providerKeyClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    string providerKey = providerKeyClaim.Value;
    string issuer = providerKeyClaim.Issuer;
    string name = claimsIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
    string emailAddress = claimsIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
}
```